# C++ STL accessing vector element

Tags: c++, vector, stl, std

What is the difference between `vector.at(i)` and `vector[i]`?

```
vector<int> myVector(6);
myVector.at(5) = 5;
```

OR

```
myVector[5] = 5;
```

I know both yield the same result, but somehow the operator `[]` is faster. Also I read about `at` checks for vector size (bounds) and returns *out of bounds* error, whereas `[]` does not.

However I saw that if try to assign:

```
myVector[8] = 1;
```

I get a similar *out of range* error in debug mode.

Then what is the meaning of `at` ? Why is it in the STL ?

Comment: It might be that in debug mode your specific vector implementation have range checks even for the `[]` operator. You really have to check the documentation for the library you are using.

Comment: Any reference should tell you. If you have disbeliefs of the validity, look in the standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`operator []` for `std::vector` will return a reference to the area of memory whether it was allocated for the vector or not. Accessing an unallocated area of memory is Undefined Behavior, whereas `at` will throw an exception before any of that occurs. As @JoachimPileborg said in the comments the unspecified behavior of `operator []` includes throwing exceptions.

Comment: To add to this, *unspecified behavior* **includes** throwing exceptions.

Comment: Thanks, so there's a specific exception connected to at(). I think I have my platform supporting debugging implementation for the container "vector". I debugged through entire process and see the cause of error while developing. Before assignment, it bound-checks for the operator "[]", too. Actually, aren't many of the platforms already doing this? Why even anyone choose "at" anyways, bearing in mind that it works slower?

Comment: @C.CanberkBacı, Because it's guaranteed to throw an exception if you go out of bounds, even in release mode. Depending on what your program is like, that can be good or bad.